# WooCommerce Checkout Template without table breaks JS functionality

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I changed the **frontend templates** (override by copying the file(s) into my custom theme folder) of the **cart** and **checkout** page by replacing some table-row-columns-constructs with div containers in order to create a (in my opinion) clearer layout, also for handling responsive layout changes.

It seems, the Wordpress hook/action `woocommerce_checkout_order_review` triggered from the template `checkout/form-checkout.php` template uses the code from `cart/cart-shipping.php` which is fine, because ist keeps the list containing the choosable shipping methods consistant on both pages.

A 'critical' change was: removing the `td` and `th` tags, and replacing `<tr class="shipping">` with `<div class="shipping">` in `cart/cart-shipping.php`.

**This leads to the problem:**

Clicking a list item of the shipping_methods ul triggers the events `update_checkout` and `updated_checkout`, which (i think) are responsible for updating the cart/chekout page.
With my changed HTML templates things are not working as they should; with every click the whole `ul` gets replicated.
I could not find any occurences of `tr.shipping` or `.shipping` in the woocommerce [js code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/master/assets/js/frontend).

Why is changing the template structure breaking the jQuery code? And how can I achieve that change without breaking?

Comment: I can see references to the selector 'tr.shiping' in the file "\woocommerce\assets\js\admin\meta-boxes-order.js".  Are you refering to the admin screen?  This is the only place I can see where it would cause an issue with you renaming the tr to a div in the script files.

Comment: I just updated my question to be a little bit clearer. No, I am refering to the frontend. I also could not find occurences of selectors, that could fail mathing the renamed `<div class="shipping"></div>`

Comment: any luck with this? If you provide a link I might be able to help more.

Answer (score 1):

**without more code it's very hard to say. Perhaps if you could provide a link I can assist more?**

Going blind, it sounds like this is an issue tied to clicking...

I can confirm that in [`assets/js/admin/meta-boxes-order.js`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/admin/meta-boxes-order.js) there are several references to `tr.shipping` from ***line 250-251*** and ***lines 541, 786 and 874***. It will likely be these lines that are causing the issue.

It's kind of hackish what you are trying to do...and without being able to test it's hard to say or confirm, but try duplicating those concerned functions but only call it on your `div.shipping`

See where that nets you out.

Comment: You are right. It's not a good idea to change the markup in this way. I feel a little bit frustrated about the fact, that markup and functionality are not well decoupled. But on the other hand, WooCommerce is a quite nice piece of software. I will have to live with the table layout.

Comment: Ideally they wouldn't target with div. It might be worth making a pull request to their repo with that change?